# Should I contact the recruiter who didn't respond to my e-mail, through Linkedin?

Tags: salary, recruitment, email, linkedin

I have recently interviewed for a developer role at a tech company and the interviews went well. In the final interview, the manager mentioned that he got good feedback from the interviewers and that the recruiter would contact me soon to give me the details about the company and other offer details. I recently received a response from the recruiter where the recruiter wanted to set up a call to negotiate salary requirements and offer details to which I responded with my available times. I didn't get a response for a day and so I sent a follow up mail to give my availability for the next day. But,  I didnt' get a response yet. Is it a good idea to wait , if so.. how long would be advisable? Is contacting through LinkedIn a good idea? or would I come off as being desperate?

Comment: In my experience (ymmv), if a recruiter is not barking up your tree to contact you for placement, it's likely that he is aggressively pitching one of the other 3-4 candidates he has submitted in addition to you.

Comment: Recruiters don't care if you are desperate or highly sought after. They just want a cut of whatever you are making. So contact them in any way that works and if you don't hear from them, contact the person you interviewed you and say you are still really interested in the position but are having difficulty working with the recruiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, contacting through LinkedIn wouldn't be good. Phone call would be much better if you are at the point of having an offer and want to have the conversation to nail down details. Sending a message that may or may not easily be seen wouldn't be a good strategy to my mind.

My suggestion is to have a point in time where you have 10-15 minutes to have the conversation and call the recruiter leaving voice mail if necessary. The idea here is that you want to have a conversation and time matters a great deal here as offers not accepted within a few days could cause problems as some companies may have a limited time that an offer is out there.